# Discrete Mathematics problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider this equation:

$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$

with these following constraints:

$x_i ≥ 0;\; i = 1,2,\ldots, k$

How would I go about formulating each of the following problems as a variation of the above problem? I have the answer key, but it's one of those useless keys that just give an answer with no explanation or steps shown so I am completely stuck.

1. Determine the number of ways to select k objects with replacements
   from a set of n objects.

Answer: $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = k;$
        $\;x_i ≥ 0; i = 1; 2; \ldots; n$.

(b) Determine the number of ways to place $n$ nondistinguisable balls in $k$
boxes.

Answer: $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n;$
        $\;x_i ≥ 0; i = 1; 2; \ldots; k$.

Can anyone explain to me how to get those answers?

Answer (score 1):

**For $1$:**
$x_i$ is the number of times you selected object $i$.
For an example:  Let's say we have $4$ objects, and we want to select $3$ (with replacement).  We can:

- Select object $1$ three times, and all other objects $0$ times. ($x_1=3,\; x_2=x_3=x_4=0$)
- Select object $1$ two times, object 2 once, and all others $0$ times. ($x_1=2,\; x_2=1,\;x_3=x_4=0$)
- Etc.

**For $2$:**
$x_i$ is the number of balls in the $i$-th box.
Let's say we have 2 boxes, and 2 balls.  Then, we can:

- Place both balls in box $1$ ($x_1 = 2,\;x_2 = 0$)
- Place one ball in each box ($x_1=x_2 = 1$)
- Place both balls in box $2$ ($x_1 = 0,\;x_2=0$)

Comment: Can you go into more detail here?

Comment: @Jack It's hard to enumerate all possibilities, because the number quickly gets large.  But, does this help explain where the numbers are coming from? (edited post)

Comment: Thanks, and one last question, how do we know to set 1) for example to = k and not = n? For answer one, why isn't it x1+x2+⋯+xk=n?

Comment: @Jack I don't know exactly *why* I know that (practice has replaced conscious thought with intuition, for better or for worse), but I think it is probably because $k$ in problem $1$ represents the number of things we're selecting and *not* the total number of things.